# Remove the complete styling of an HTML button/submit

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, button, state

Is there a way of completely removing the styling of a button in Internet Explorer? I use a css sprite for my button, and everything looks ok.

But when I click the button, it moves to the top a little, it makes it look out of shape. Is there a css click state, or mousedown? I don't know what triggers that state.

I know it's not a really big deal, but sometimes it's the small things that matter.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

I think this provides a more thorough approach:

```css
button, input[type="submit"], input[type="reset"] {
 background: none;
 color: inherit;
 border: none;
 padding: 0;
 font: inherit;
 cursor: pointer;
 outline: inherit;
}
```

```html
<button>Example</button>
```

Comment: I don't think background has a 'none' - and the !important is no good.

Comment: Usually, when you're doing this you want to override existing styles that exist for a button. It's rare that you want to do this with clean, unstyled HTML, hence the use of `!important`. That said I've removed it as it's a situation decision. `background: none` is entirely valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784292/backgroundnone-vs-backgroundtransparent

Comment: To each their own regarding !important. I don't think I could work on a project where I was forced to use it. RE: 'none' Here's a reference that is better than a SO post. When you use 'background' by itself, you are really using shorthand and clobbering all the attributes.

Comment: I was driving myself nuts over the difference between styling an image and some text inside a button and having it look the same as it does outside a `<button/>`...in my case, `font: inherit;` did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: I think for accessibility purposes you probably want to leave that outline there. otherwise when you tab over it there is no visual cue where you are. great answer though!

Comment: For those who want to inherit the text alignment, please add `text-align: inherit;`

Comment: beware the using of `type` and `attribute` in reset.css, the type and attribute's declaration [has precedence over class' declaration](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-e&q=css+selector+specificity). Specificity is ranked uisng the sum of all the specificity factor.

Comment: Been here 50+ times. 

Comment: This is incredible: 

`{ all: initial; font: inherit; color: inherit; }`

Comment: Also `text-align: left`

Comment: Also `border-radius: 0` (especially for iOS)

Comment: I found out `user-select: inherit` is also useful to allow copy&paste (when I want to list all properties instead of `all: unset` to keep the default focus outline)

Comment: `line-height: inherit` + `letter-spacing: inherit`

Answer (score 176):

Your question says "Internet Explorer," but for those interested in other browsers, you can now use `all: unset` on buttons to unstyle them.

It doesn't work in IE, but it's well-supported everywhere else.

https://caniuse.com/css-all

**Accessibility warning:** For the sake of users who aren't using a mouse pointer, be sure to re-add some `:focus` styling, e.g. `button:focus { outline: orange auto 5px }` for [keyboard accessibility](https://www.deque.com/blog/give-site-focus-tips-designing-usable-focus-indicators/). If you're feeling lazy, you can `button:focus { outline: revert }` to revert the outline to the browser's default. https://caniuse.com/css-revert-value

(And, I hope this goes without saying, but be sure to add back *some* kind of styling so your button actually looks like a button, and preferably some `:hover` styling, too. If your button doesn't have a border, consider `cursor: pointer` as well.)

```css
button {
  all: unset;
}

button:focus {
  outline: revert;
}
```

```html
<button>check it out</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: This is not advisable for accessibility reasons. You'll need to add back all of the `outline` styles for the `:focus` element state, for instance.

Comment: @Devin Great point! I updated my post with a suggestion to re-add an `outline` style. (But I don't think there's anything _else_ that we need to re-add for a11y purposes. Do you know of anything?)

Comment: **Old Safari color warning:** Setting the text `color` of the button after using `all: unset` can fail in Safari 13.1, due to [a bug in WebKit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158782). (The bug is fixed in Safari 14 and up.) "`all: unset` is setting `-webkit-text-fill-color` to black, and that overrides color." If you need to set text `color` after using `all: unset`, be sure to set both the `color` and the `-webkit-text-fill-color` to the same color.

Comment: Using "outline: revert" is a cleaner solution than manually setting the button:focus style (though it won't work if you need to support really old browsers)

Answer (score 88):

I'm assuming that when you say '*click the button, it moves to the top a little*' you're talking about the mouse down click state for the button, and that when you release the mouse click, it returns to its normal state? And that you're disabling the default rendering of the button by using:

```
input, button, submit { border:none; }
```

If so..

Personally, I've found that you can't actually stop/override/disable this IE native action, which led me to change my markup a little to allow for this movement and not affect the overall look of the button for the various states.

This is my final mark-up:

```html
<span class="your-button-class">
    <span>
        <input type="Submit" value="View Person">
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 14):

In bootstrap 4 is easiest. 
You can use the classes: 
`bg-transparent` and `border-0`

Comment: + `shadow-none` for me and it's sufficient. Thx!

Answer (score 13):

Add simple style to your button

```
.btn {
    background: none;
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: inherit;
}
```

Comment: this is the answer I was hoping to find, I've always used (all: unset) but it removes the styling of any directive in angular. This one does the real job of removing only the styling. That's why I prefer this answer

Answer (score 11):

Try removing the border from your button:

```
input, button, submit
{
  border:none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think it's the button "active" state.

Comment: It has to be the active state, you are right +1 for that. But i did not get it to work properly

Comment: "I think" is not an answer.