# button image as form input submit button?

Tags: html, forms

```
<form method="post" action="confirm_login_credentials.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User ID:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="uid"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="pass"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="right">
                <a href="#"><img src="images/login.jpg"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I am using an image in place of a submit button. How can I submit the login details when the user clicks on the login image as a submit button does?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

You could use an [image submit button](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1):

```
<input type="image" src="images/login.jpg" alt="Submit Form" />
```

Comment: Yep. This is the best way. A side note to this: some serverside languages have different ways of getting at whether the button was pressed, normally via the X & Y coords of the mouse click. So have a nosey at the documentation on your language of choice (if you need this)

Comment: How to insert button name on the image?

Comment: This works great for a simple form submit, but if you need the image to carry a value (to determine which image/button was clicked) then you will be out of luck in FireFox - you will have to use a button with a background :-(

Comment: @ClarkKent - Yes exactly.

Comment: It may not have a value, but it has a name. And that name will appear in firefux, chram, and internet exploder with "_x" added to the end. Unfortunately, the value for _x and _y will be coordinates rather than an actual value. However: If you need a value, provide one in a hidden field with a matching name and grab it based on which "_x" field is present. Unclicked images names will not be submitted or present in the POST array.

Answer (score 38):

Late to the conversation...

But, why not use css?  That way you can keep the button as a submit type.

html:

```
<input type="submit" value="go" />
```

css:

```
button, input[type="submit"] {
    background:url(/images/submit.png) no-repeat;"
}
```

Works like a charm.

**EDIT**: If you want to remove the default button styles, you can use the following css:

```
button, input[type="submit"]{
    color: inherit;
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    font: inherit;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: inherit;
}
```

from this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2460100/remove-the-complete-styling-of-an-html-button-submit)

Comment: That will still show the image button style, not ideal when you want to show only an image as a button.

Comment: @Shimmy - The default button style wasn't an issue for me, but I've updated my answer to include how to remove the default button style.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a second image to give the effect of a button being pressed. Just add the "pressed" button image in the `HTML` before the input image:

```
<img src="http://integritycontractingofva.com/images/go2.jpg" id="pressed"/>
<input id="unpressed" type="submit" value=" " style="background:url(http://integritycontractingofva.com/images/go1.jpg) no-repeat;border:none;"/>
```

And use `CSS` to change the opacity of the "unpressed" image on hover:

```
#pressed, #unpressed{position:absolute; left:0px;}
#unpressed{opacity: 1; cursor: pointer;}
#unpressed:hover{opacity: 0;}
```

I use it for the blue "GO" button on [this page](http://integritycontractingofva.com/Home_Services.php)

Answer (score 1):

This might be helpful

```
<form action="myform.cgi"> 
 <input type="file" name="fileupload" value="fileupload" id="fileupload">
 <label for="fileupload"> Select a file to upload</label> 
 <br>
 <input type="image" src="/wp-content/uploads/sendform.png" alt="Submit" width="100"> </form>
```

Read more: https://html.com/input-type-image/#ixzz5KD3sJxSp

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container-fluid login-container">
    <div class="row">
        <form (ngSubmit)="login('da')">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="login-text">
                        Login
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-signin">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="login-go-div">
                    <input type="image" src="../../../assets/images/svg/login-go-initial.svg" class="login-go"
                         onmouseover="this.src='../../../assets/images/svg/login-go.svg'"
                         onmouseout="this.src='../../../assets/images/svg/login-go-initial.svg'"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the working code for it.

Answer (score 0):

Make the submit button the main image you are using. So the form tags would come first then submit button which is your only image so the image is your clickable image form. Then just make sure to put whatever you are passing before the submit button code.