# Change CSS Cuffon button

Tags: html, css

I have a form in my webpage which have a CSS button, that button is embedded in a way i have never seen, in a cuffon related method perhaps (?)

Anyway i am trying to change that button to my button but dont know how to assign the submit method to it..

The current button:

```
<p><input type="submit" value="Send"/></p>
```

[The Page](http://www.tranceil.co.il/10kcontest/)

How should i go about adding a png button and give it the submit value?

Comment: Are you looking at the following element in your page: `<input type="image" value="Submit" src="<img/newbuttonsend-small.png>">` ?

Comment: thats one way of trying to do it yes, but it didnt recognized the png location, although its correct

Comment: The following may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381609/button-image-as-form-input-submit-button  Just update the image to your specifications and design.

Comment: @Martina Let me check into this and get a better reference.  I will update my post later.  I don't see this construct often and I am curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following syntax:

```
<input type="image" value="Submit" src="img/newbuttonsend-small.png">
```

There should not be angle-brackets in the file path/name.

**Using INPUT with image as Submit in a Form**

Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

See the section discussing:

> **image**
>       Creates a graphical submit button. The value of the src attribute specifies the URI of the image that will decorate the button. For accessibility reasons, authors should provide alternate text for the image via the alt attribute.

When you click on the image, the browser echos the x-y coordinates of the pointer location, which may be useful in certain applications.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="image" value="Submit" src="yourImage.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<button name="xyz" value="something" type='submit'>
    <img src='mybutton.png' alt='' />
</button>
```

Comment: Thanx for the reply..i'm getting this weird grey button..not the one i entered...http://www.tranceil.co.il/10kcontest/

Comment: @TonalDev : **<button type="Submit" value="something" name="send" style="opacity: 0;">** - note the opacity - 0 means invisible use something nearer 100 :)