# Input type button with image

Tags: javascript, html

I want an event to be triggered when the image is clicked, but I cannot figure out how to make that happen. Is it possible for an event to be triggered when an image is clicked?

```
<form>
  <input type="button" name="button" value="Download" onclick="passWord()" class="button"/>
</form>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/29mf5wf9/

Comment: You should use an input type "image":
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3381609/button-image-as-form-input-submit-button

Answer (score 3):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL0n3mcj/)

You can use `image` instead of `button` for `input type`. It will still be a button.

**HTML**

```
<input type="image" src="image/path" name="button" value="Download" onclick="passWord()" class="button"/>
```

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image)

> The `<input type="image">` is a graphical submit button.

See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL0n3mcj/1/) with a javascript function working..

Comment: is it ok if you use jQuery?

Comment: @RandomChannel jQuery for what? to add the image?

Comment: for when the image is clicked

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify image in the type.

```
<form>
    <input type="image" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logos/so/so-logo.png" name="button" value="Download" onclick="passWord()" class="button"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find the information: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_src.asp

```
<input type="image" src="your_image.png" name="button" value="Download" alt="Download" onclick="passWord();" class="button" width="your_image_width" height="your_image_height">
```

Comment: the button "runs" a script that verifies a password to download a file, if i use input type image it doesnt run the script, just refreshes the page....

Comment: If the another answers work, use one of them. If it is not, I can solve it and re-edit my answer in 2 minutes @questionador

Comment: I have edited my answer, could you please check it @questionador ?

Comment: is it possible to add a authentication form to that button? or is it just dumb for me to try to do it that way?