# background:none vs background:transparent what is the difference?

Tags: css, background

Is there a **difference between** these two CSS properties:

```
background: none;
background: transparent;
```

1. Are they both valid?
2. Which one should be used and why?

Answer (score 134, accepted):

There is no difference between them.

If you don't specify a value for any of the half-dozen properties that `background` is a shorthand for, then it is set to its default value. `none` and `transparent` are the defaults.

One explicitly sets the `background-image` to `none` and implicitly sets the `background-color` to `transparent`. The other is the other way around.

Comment: @herman — No, they can't. This is the same as `background-color: transparent; background-image: none;`. A user stylesheet might override one or both of those values, but it will do so exactly as if `background-color: transparent; background-image: none;` had been written explicitly.

Comment: So, you are saying the "initial" property value (which is used for unspecified properties) overrides even user agent stylesheets?  Do you have any reference?

Comment: User agent stylesheets implement the spec, which defines the initial property value of those properties as `transparent` and `none`.

Answer (score 75):

As aditional information on **@Quentin** answer, and as he rightly says,
`background` CSS property itself, is a shorthand for:

```
background-color
background-image
background-repeat
background-attachment
background-position
```

That's mean, you can group all styles in one, like:

```
background: red url(../img.jpg) 0 0 no-repeat fixed;
```

This would be (in this example):

```
background-color: red;
background-image: url(../img.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: 0 0;
```

So... when you set: `background:none;`
<strike>you are saying that all the background properties are set to **none**...</strike>
You are saying that `background-image: none;` and all the others to the `initial` state (as they are not being declared).
So, `background:none;` is:

```
background-color: initial;
background-image: none;
background-repeat: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-position: initial;
```

Now, when you define only the color (in your case `transparent`) then you are basically saying:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-image: initial;
background-repeat: initial;
background-attachment: initial;
background-position: initial;
```

I repeat, *as @Quentin rightly says* the `default` `transparent` and `none` values **in this case** are the same, so in your example and for your original question, No, there's no difference between them.

But!.. if you say `background:none` Vs `background:red` then yes... there's a big diference, as I say, the first would set all properties to `none/default` and the second one, will only change the `color` and remains the rest in his `default` state.

### So in brief:

**Short answer**: No, there's no difference at all (in your example and orginal question)
**Long answer**: Yes, there's a big difference, but depends directly on the properties granted to attribute.

---

### Upd1: Initial value (aka `default`)

Initial value the concatenation of the initial values of its longhand properties:

```
background-image: none
background-position: 0% 0%
background-size: auto auto
background-repeat: repeat
background-origin: padding-box
background-style: is itself a shorthand, its initial value is the concatenation of its own longhand properties
background-clip: border-box
background-color: transparent
```

### See more `background` descriptions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background)

---

Upd2: Clarify better the `background:none;` specification.

Comment: thx for answer what are the default values for background-image, background repeat...? do they depend on browser? If I understand your explanation, it's better to use background:none so none of the values are set to default?

Comment: Have you tried what you post??  Are all values setted to none? Check the `console` on this demo http://jsfiddle.net/dnzy2/6/

Comment: *when you set: background:none;
you are saying that all the background properties are set to none...*  Is not a way to say is wrong

Comment: +1, This must be the accepted answer (if it's correct).

Comment: according to MDN, initial value of `background-image` is `none`, so `background-image: none` === `background-image: initial`, hence, `background: none` === `background: transparent`, I guess

Answer (score 12):

To complement the other answers: if you want to reset all background properties to their initial value (which includes `background-color: transparent` and `background-image: none`) without explicitly specifying any value such as `transparent` or `none`, you can do so by writing:

```
background: initial;
```

Comment: Be careful, IE does not support `initial`. see [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/#search=initial) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)