# Anyway to prevent the Blue highlighting of elements in Chrome when clicking quickly?

Tags: css, google-chrome

Most of the time I'm not worried about it but I have an image carousel and if I click on the next and previous divs quickly, they will be highlighted in Chrome.

I tried using outline:none but no effect. Are there any solutions out there?

Comment: I do not see this effect on the current Chrome version

Comment: I know that your use case is different, but for anyone else who might want to remove it from all links I do not recommend to do that. I have tried to remove it on a PWA, but without the visual feedback, the user perception is that the app is slower.

Answer (score 303, accepted):

You can use pure CSS to accomplish this. Here's a rundown for multi-browser support, chrome being covered by the first line and the final `:focus` bit. Details below.

```
.noSelect {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.noSelect:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Simply add the `class="noSelect"` attribute to the element you wish to apply this class to. I would highly recommend giving this CSS solution a try. Some have suggested using JavaScript, but I believe this is the cleanest solution.

**For Android/Safari mobile/Edge**

`-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;` is the additional rule you may be looking for. Affects Chrome desktop (esp. with touchscreen) and mobile devices. [Here's a warning about using this non-standard property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color), as well as [some accessibility concerns with suggestions](https://www.a11yproject.com/posts/2013-01-25-never-remove-css-outlines/). Best practice is to replace the highlight with your own styling.

*UPDATE: Later versions of Chrome...*

A commenter on this answer pointed out `:focus { outline: none !important;}` is needed for newer versions of Chrome. Answer adapted to include this, as well! Ah, ever-changing standards.

Comment: For Chrome only, you probably only need `user-select` and `webkit-user-select`.

Comment: This is the solution I am going with since I am only having the highlighting issue in Chrome and it works great. Thanks to everybody who participated!

Comment: Couldn't make it work with Chrome on Android. I had to use `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);`

Comment: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;`  is the key part on Chrome

Comment: For chrome on android -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; - Worked for me thanks!

Comment: -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; helped on SAFARI mobile too! I was using the onclick event in some image buttons within <a> tags, to fire a script to toggle a brief animation. No issue with mouse clicks, but the short duration blue box around the images on SAFARI mobile really was killing the effect! I ended up just applying all this to the whole body CSS for now.

Comment: Does not work on the current versions of Chrome (78.0.3904.108). Use `:focus { outline: none !important;}` as found in Jeff L.'s answer below.

Comment: excellent solution! I first asked this like 6 years ago, glad there's finally an answer for this, thanks!

Answer (score 337):

For Chrome on Android, you can use the [-webkit-tap-highlight-color CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color):

> -webkit-tap-highlight-color is a non-standard CSS property that sets the 
>   color of the highlight that appears over a link while it's being
>   tapped. The highlighting indicates to the user that their tap is being
>   successfully recognized, and indicates which element they're tapping
>   on.

To remove the highlighting completely, you can set the value to `transparent`:

```css
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
```

Be aware that this might have consequences on accessibility: see [outlinenone.com](http://www.outlinenone.com/)

Comment: I found that when you run on a touchscreen for example, Chrome will behave much like it does on Android. I had a <div> which would flash blue whenever you clicked somewhere inside it. Only when I used this answer did it stop. Thanks!

Comment: None of the other css attys will do this.
So important since the tap highlighting distorts the appearance of whatever is clicked, slurring your visual language.

Comment: `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;` seems to work too.

Comment: I liked this, for touch events it is a must! This information has "out of chart" usefullness!

Comment: Very useful. I tried out many different things but this worked well.

Comment: For the sake of accessibility, it would be worth keeping some indicator that the link has been clicked. You could use rgba with a slight opacity (adjusted depending on what your initial link/button background colour is): `-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)`

Answer (score 76):

I'm running Chrome version 60 and none of the previous CSS answers worked.

I found that Chrome was adding the blue highlight via the `outline` style.  Adding the following CSS fixed it for me:

```
:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

Comment: this is the working one for Chrome (version 61) on Android

Comment: Works for more recent versions of Chrome. Thanks!

Comment: Super, was wondering why my trusty `user-select:none` was getting nowhere

Comment: I tried everything but this worked like charm. Thanks for saving my hairs!

Answer (score 38):

But, sometimes, even with `user-select` and `touch-callout` turned off, `cursor: pointer;` may cause this effect, so, just set `cursor: default;` and it'll work.

Comment: This is a correct answer, `cursor: pointer;` is really causing highlight. But `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;` is more universal solution.

Comment: @yanot: read the warning about `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` before labelling it a relatively *universal solution*: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color

Comment: @HassanBaig I think it's obvious that I didn't mean *universal cross-browser*, but *in this context, i.e. across different versions of chrome*

Comment: thanks - none of the other solutions worked for me. Had to remove the cursor pointer to make the blue highlight go away

Comment: `cursor: default` did the trick for me when nothing else worked.

Answer (score 9):

To remove the blue overlay on mobiles, you can use one of the following:

```css
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* transparent with keyword */
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0); /* transparent with rgba */
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: hsla(0,0,0,0); /* transparent with hsla */
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #00000000; /* transparent with hex with alpha */
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: #0000; /* transparent with short hex with alpha */
```

However, [unlike other properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20784292), you can't use

```css
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: none; /* none keyword */
```

In DevTools, this will show up as an 'invalid property value' or something.

---

To remove the blue/black/orange outline when focused, use this:

```css
:focus {
    outline: none; /* no outline - for most browsers */
    box-shadow: none; /* no box shadow - for some browsers or if you are using Bootstrap */
}
```

The reason why I removed the `box-shadow` is because Bootsrap (and some browsers) sometimes add it to focused elements, so you can remove it using this.

But if anyone is navigating with a keyboard, they will get very confused indeed, because they rely on this outline to navigate. So you can replace it instead

```css
:focus {
    outline: 100px dotted #f0f; /* 100px dotted pink outline */
}
```

---

You can [target taps on mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6063308) using `:hover` or `:active`, so you could use those to help, possibly. Or it could get confusing.

---

Full code:

```
element {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; /* remove tap highlight */
}
element:focus {
    outline: none; /* remove outline */
    box-shadow: none; /* remove box shadow */
}
```

---

Other information:

- If you would like to customise the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` then you should set it to a semi-transparent color so the element underneath doesn't get hidden when tapped
- Please [don't remove the outline](https://outlinenone.com) from focused elements, or add some more styles for them.
- `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` has not got great browser support and is not standard. You can still use it, but watch out!

Answer (score 3):

I had similar issue with `<input type="range" />` and I solved it with

> -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;

```css
input[type="range"]{
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
 <input type="range" id="volume" name="demo"
         min="0" max="11">
  <label for="volume">Demo</label>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try creating a handler for select event on those elements and in the handler you can clear the selection.

Take a look at this:

[Clear Text Selection with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169786/clear-text-selection-with-javascript)

It's an example of clearing the selection. You'd only need to modify it to work only on the specific element that you need.

Comment: So it can't be fixed by CSS, huh? Could I just clear the selected text inside my click handler? EDIT- Thanks for the example. This sucks that it has to be handled via javascript. I was hoping it was just a CSS issue.

Comment: Also, will this have any accessibility impact?

Comment: You could clear the text in the click handler, but take a look at @smts answer with pure CSS.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score -10):

This works the best for me:

```
.noSelect:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: This is BAD and a road to certain future hell. No offence.

Comment: what if the background of the website is not white?

Comment: This is not maintainable. No one do this please.