# Have this code so when a user presses the up or down key the balloon grows or shrinks. Need balloon to burst to "" when it reaches font size over 70

Tags: javascript, html

So far the balloon should only be able to reach max 70 font before it bursts. I need to turn the balloon into "". The event  listener needs to be removed when the balloon bursts.

```js
let para = document.querySelector('p');
para.style.fontSize = '24px';

window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  var sizeAsInteger = parseInt(para.style.fontSize, 10);

  if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {
    sizeAsInteger += 10;
  } else {
    sizeAsInteger -= 10;
  }

  para.style.fontSize = sizeAsInteger + 'px';
});
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p></p>
</body>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific, _concise_ question.

Comment: I see no attempt to do what you describe in your code. You're expected to make an effort and show your progress.

Comment: Lol, I love this idea!

Comment: @Shmack https://stackoverflow.com/a/45898043/2813224

Comment: @zer00ne BLEW MY MIND! I didn't think that something like that could be done with pure css! Wow!!!

Comment: @Shmack https://stackoverflow.com/a/54821785/2813224

Comment: Bro, what the heck. Crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
let para = document.querySelector("p");

para.style.fontSize = "24px";

const increaseSize = e => {
  var sizeAsInteger = parseInt(para.style.fontSize, 10);

  if (sizeAsInteger >= 70) {
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", increaseSize);
    return (para.innerHTML = "");
  }

  if (e.key == "ArrowUp") {
    sizeAsInteger += 10;
  } else {
    sizeAsInteger -= 10;
  }

  para.style.fontSize = sizeAsInteger + "px";
};

window.addEventListener("keydown", increaseSize);
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<p></p>
```