# Disable blue stroke effect on button clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, button

I have a button defined as follows:

```
<button style={{backgroundColor: 'transparent', border: 0}} onClick={() => back()}>
   <i style={{color: '#3a6464'}} className='fa fa-arrow-circle-left fa-fw fa-3x'/>
</button>
```

[image: button]

When I click the icon button I get a blue stoke effect:

[image: effect]

How can I disable this effect or at least change the blue color?

Comment: Set `outline: none` for `button` in css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the focus css:

```
button:focus {outline:0;}
```

For touchscreens:

```
@media (hover: hover) {
    button:hover {
        outline:0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't seem to work when the click doesn't result in the button not appearing on screen anymore (i.e navigation), still getting blue box

Comment: @Mugen I apologize I'm not understanding your comment. Could you explain more?

Comment: I was missing some information there, the simplified case is this: in touch screens, where chrome adds accessibility features, and the button callback does nothing, I'm still getting a blue border

Comment: I added to my answer try that out

Comment: the following worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21003770/1236401 , I'll try out your solution as well. thank you very much!