# Is there a way to remove the blue highlight for a checkbox?

Tags: html, css

I have noticed that this checkbox will sometimes display a blue highlight when checked on certain browsers. I'm not entirely sure where this comes from, as I have only managed to see this behavior from Safari on my iPhone, as well as Device Mode from Chrome Developer Tools. However, desktop Chrome and Firefox do not include the highlight at all.

[image]

```css
.center {
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.switch {
 width: 120px;
 height: 68px;
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.switch input {
 visibility: hidden;
}

.slider {
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: absolute;
 transition: 0.375s;
 border-radius: 68px;
 background-color: #414b55;
}

.slider:before {
 left: 8px;
 bottom: 8px;
 width: 52px;
 height: 52px;
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 transition: 0.375s;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background-color: #ffffff;
}

input:checked + .slider {
 background-color: #fa6400;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
 transform: translateX(52px);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="center">
   <label class="switch">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <span class="slider"></span>
   </label>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Could someone explain where it comes from and how to remove this effect?

Comment: `[type=checkbox] {user-select: none}`

Comment: That did not seem to remove the highlight.

Comment: I added an image of the blue highlight, just to make it more clear.

Comment: It was worth a try, it works for real browsers.

Comment: `[type=checkbox] {outline: 0}` you might need to add `!important`

Comment: I have no issue with the styling as it is when it comes to desktop browsers. The issue seems to be caused by mobile interaction.

Comment: Regarding the `outline: 0` suggestion, please don't do this. See http://www.outlinenone.com/ (this is bad for a11y / accessibility).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It may be the `tap-highlight-color` which you can make transparent with the following code:

```css
.switch {
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent
}
```

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21003770/753676 which mentions this and the `user-select: none` and `-webkit-touch-callout: none` approach.

But for Chrome on mobile you still need the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color` setting.

Comment: Without knowing the HTML and CSS? what is the code snippet for then?

Comment: Thank you! This solved the issue. Although, I did include my code from the very beginning :)

Comment: Ah sorry, just saw it now =) To which element did you apply it?

Comment: The input or the label?

Comment: I simply applied it to the label tag.