# How to get rid of the blue box which appears on-click around the element clicked in mobile view?

Tags: css, highlight, box

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0BDAU.png)

This blue box appears only in mobile view. I have tried to set :focus{ outline:none;} and :active{outline:none;}. Also tried using -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is a feature specific to Chrome. When I tried adding the following CSS from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21003535/anyway-to-prevent-the-blue-highlighting-of-elements-in-chrome-when-clicking-quic), it seemed to resolve the issue:

```
.gooey-selected {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: I was using  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; on the wrong selector . Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the code? You need to do `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;` however, it could be that the selector you have for that element is not right

Comment: I was using  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; on the wrong selector as you say. Silly me. Thank you for the help.