# Blue Square Box Fill showing when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, button

[image]

I have created a button and every time I long press it or click on it, a square blue fill is showing, I tried removing it with `outline: 0` and `-webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;`, but it didn't work. Here is my code :-

````css
.mybutton:focus {
    outline: none;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.40);
}```
````

Comment: did this happen on mobile or pc?

Comment: it happens on mobile

Comment: This is a common issue on mobile, try referring to https://stackoverflow.com/a/21003770/14187638.

**EDIT:** I just realized, you already have tried the method can you please provide more code and minimal reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example?