# Transparent color vs rgba(0,0,0,0)

Tags: css

Is there any major advantage to use:

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

instead of:

```
background-color: transparent;
```

?

Comment: related : [CSS background:none vs background:transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784292/css-backgroundnone-vs-backgroundtransparent)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Behaviour is exactly the same, but `transparent` [is compatible also with IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=transparent).
`RGBA` is more advanced (but [lacks IE8 support](http://caniuse.com/#search=rgba)) and allows you to quickly modify it, in case you would like an "*almost transparent*" color, without need to completely change attribute.

For example, it could be very quick to set

```
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

Due to default behaviour of browsers that ignored unrecognized properties, is possible to combine them in order to use new one in newer browsers, but leave a fallback for older ones, simply typing both of them:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
```

Or, more useful, in case of alreasy cited *almost transparent* backgrounds, you can write:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
```

New browsers will set `rgba(0,0,0,0.1)` as background, overriding previous `transparent` declaration, but IE8 will set `transparent` as background, because it will ignore unrecognized `rgba()` value, so a slightly different result but in according to *Graceful Degradation* principle.

Comment: I really don't know this: my doubt (but it's only a doubt) is that a browser non compatibile with rgba coud simply ignore this declaration and not setting `none` as value. In case that this declaration is the unique one, behaviour would be what you described, but in case of a declaration that should overwrite another one.... if browser ignores this rule.... you don't obtain `background:none` equivalent.

Comment: The normal behaviour for browsers when they encounter a decalration that they don't understand/support is to not do anything as they don't know what to do. So the `background-color` property would remain unchanged and stay default witch is in fact `transparent` and not `none` ([MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background))

Comment: In case the decalration is supposed to override an other one then it wouldn't work though, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

To Note: `background_color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);` would be more accurate but the same. As stated `background_color: transparent;` would be supported in older browsers.

Using the **background_color** is not the issue as it is used universally in  both indicators.
The issue of question is in the assignment of **transparent** -vs- **rgba**.

**transparent** - obviously sets the background to a transparent background with no color option; the other choice is a specified color assingment in hex or other accepted color values such as `blue  rgb(x,x,x)  rgba(x,x,x,x)  #xxxxxx  hsl(x,x,x)  hsla(x,x,x,x)`  etc.

**`rgba(x,x,x,x)`** however is and is not a horse of a different color as it is more extensive and needs to be broken down to explain. Firstly the difference is that you are assigning a color and setting the transparency,

The "rgb" portion of the setting stands for **red green blue** representing the first 3 zero settings `(0,0,255,X)` and each 0 accepts values from 0 to 255. Playing with these three values in combination mixes the color settings to produce a single color.

The "**a**" in (rgb**a**) and its zero setting (x,x,x,**0**) is the ALPHA channel that sets the opacity/transparency of the first three combined colors (**x,x,x**,?). Of special note this last zero value(x,x,x,**0**) accepts range of values from **`0.0`** to **`1.0`** . A `0.0` setting is fully transparent while `1.0` is solid. So, using the setting `rgba(x,x,x,0.5)` would produce a given color at half transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a scenario where you can spot a difference between the two.

I have a case where I want to place a red diagonal line as a strikethrough a div which needs the background to use transparent and not rgba(0, 0, 0, 0).

This is my code:

```
<div className="relative">
  <p>Text here</p>
  <div style={{background: "linear-gradient(to left top, transparent 45%, #d10813 48.5%, #d10813 51.5%, transparent 55%)"}} className="absolute top-0 w-full h-full"></div>
</div>
```

If you switch transparent 45% to rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45) you can see that it doesn't work anymore.

So, in a few words transparent with opacity is not the same as black with opacity obviously.

(The code is in react and the classnames are from tailwindcss)

Answer (score -3):

you want a transparent background in React Native, apply this piece of code

```
backgroundColor: 'rgba(1,1,1,0.1)'
```

Comment: I really see no reason why you would do this.
Please elaborate your answer...

Comment: if you ever used React-Native , you would automatically understand this ... no need of elaboration