# What is the default background color for HTML elements? White or Transparent?

Tags: html, css

I just got stuck with a simple problem to figure it out. What is the default background color of HTML elements? Is it white or transparent?

Comment: Related: [background:none vs background:transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784292/backgroundnone-vs-backgroundtransparent)

Comment: not sure why you'd need to ask this on stackoverflow rather then adding a div with a background colour that has child divs (without a background colour), then previewing the result in a browser?

Comment: @Aaron I asked it because I want to have the experts answers as I was writing an important paper. I was somehow sure about transparent but still want to confirm it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The default background color is transparent.

See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-color

Comment: Is there a setting such as 'default' or you must use `transparent`?

Answer (score 6):

The standard background color is transparent as can be seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp).

> The background-color property sets the background color of an element.
>
> The background of an element is the total size of the element, including padding and border (but not the margin).
>
> Default Value: Transparent