# CSS use of :not() selector on an inner table

Tags: css, css-selectors, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using AjaxControlToolkit and the main-page CSS is also affecting the inner "calendar" popup.

I've reduced everything to a simple 1-page example showing what I want, what I've tried, and the "ugly workaround". I'm looking for a proper CSS solution.

All information is in the example below:

```css
table.my_table_padding {border-collapse: collapse;}

/* starting point (looks a mess) */
/* table.my_table_padding tr td {padding: 20px;background-color: greenyellow;} */

/* My attempts (neither worked) */ 
/* :not(.ajax_calendar) table.my_table_padding tr td {padding: 20px;background-color: orange;} */ 
/* :not(div.ajax_calendar) table.my_table_padding tr td {padding: 20px;background-color: orange;} */ 

/* The workaround that is a mess and a horrid bodge - is there a better way in a single class, using a :not() ? */
table.my_table_padding tr td {padding: 20px;background-color: greenyellow;}
div.ajax__calendar table.my_table_padding tr td {padding: 0;background-color: white;}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="my_table_padding">
  <tr>
    <td>Header-text</td>
    <td>Sample Text... Sample Text...<br />Text is here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Header-text</td>
    <td>
      <div class="ajax__calendar">
        <!-- Actually using a popup nuget:AjaxControlToolkit, this is an example -->
        See: <a href="https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx">AjaxControlToolkit Sample Page</a>
        <table border="1" class="my_table_padding">
          <tr><td colspan="7">Popup calendar-control</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
          <tr><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**EDIT 1** (to clarify what I'm after)

Basically, I've found one ugly way to achieve the desired display results
1 - adding the original CSS-rule [table.my_table_padding tr td]
2 - Adding another CSS-rule underneath it [div.ajax__calendar table.my_table_padding tr td] that has the reverse-effect of all the changes in the first rule

but, this approach seems messy. I was wondering if there was a better way of phrasing the original (CSS rule 1), in such a way that it picked all tables other than children of the "div class=ajax__calendar" element.

**EDIT 2 - The original ASP.NET Webforms code**

```
<asp:DetailsView runat="server" ID="detv_Main" CssClass="my_table_padding detv_example">
 <Fields>
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Start Date" SortExpression="EventStartDate">
   <EditItemTemplate>
     <asp:TextBox ID="txt_EventStartDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind(example) %>' CssClass="edit_background"></asp:TextBox>
     <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="calext_EventStartDate" TargetControlID="txt_EventStartDate" runat="server" Format="d MMM yyyy" />
  </EditItemTemplate>
  <ItemTemplate>Example date</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Your question is pretty unclear. You want all of your CSS to NOT affect `<div class="ajax__calendar">`?

Comment: Your attempts failed primarily because you're running the selector from the bottom up. That's not how CSS works. CSS works in a "cascade": from the top down.

Comment: I don't think your problem is the `:not()` selector. It's actually your need for a parent selector in CSS, which doesn't exist. https://stackoverflow.com/q/1014861/3597276

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: @ThomasBennett - I already have the "starting point" css in a legacy project - I want to find a what to modify it so that the calendar-popup isn't affected by the existing padding -- I was hoping that I could use some sort of "table.my padding" (where the table is not a child of any element with the ajax_calendar class)

Comment: @Michael_B - yes, that me be the case, but I haven't been able to find the correct css (using the not() selector or anything else) to achieve what I wanted (which is for "my_table" to affect all tables (and child cells) except for the calendar-popups which all happens to be wrapped in a "div class=ajax_calendar"

Comment: @disinfor - I've just had a look - I don't see it as being a duplicate. Rather than saying "is there an operator that does x y or z, I've asked a specific question on a single worked example. -- (Just about to modify the question to try and make it clearer)

Comment: @Michael_B - Just about to add the "real" code (part of a legacy ASP.NET Webforms project) - I can't think of any other significant "unique feature" (multiple pages use the same control, although at least the "site-wide common css-files" are easily accessible and modifiable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as making the CSS only apply to the parent table, you need to use the [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) (`>`) in addition to the `:not`. Without the child combinator, the inner `table` still matches the rule because the descendants of the inner `table` (which is excluded by the `:not`) are also descendants of the outer `table` (which is not excluded by the `:not`).

To use the child combinator with a `table` and `tr` [you have to include the implicit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568877/2763026) `tbody`. The net result for your selector is this:

```
:not(.ajax__calendar) table.my_table_padding > tbody > tr > td
```

That will get you most of the way there. However, [the default background color is transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35205683/what-is-the-default-background-color-for-html-elements-white-or-transparent), so your inner `table` will have the same background as the outer table unless something in between sets it. I chose to set it directly on `.ajax__calendar` but you could choose to put it on any descendant of the outer `td` (where the background color is getting set).

```css
table.my_table_padding {border-collapse: collapse;}

:not(.ajax__calendar) > table.my_table_padding > tbody > tr > td {padding: 20px;background-color: greenyellow;}

/* This is necessary since the transparent background of the inner table would otherwise should the greenyellow of the outer table. This could be set at a different level as desired */
div.ajax__calendar {background-color: white;}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="my_table_padding">
  <tr>
    <td>Header-text</td>
    <td>Sample Text... Sample Text...<br />Text is here</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Header-text</td>
    <td>
      <div class="ajax__calendar">
        <!-- Actually using a popup nuget:AjaxControlToolkit, this is an example -->
        See: <a href="https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.devexpress.com/Calendar/Calendar.aspx">AjaxControlToolkit Sample Page</a>
        <table border="1" class="my_table_padding">
          <tr><td colspan="7">Popup calendar-control</td></tr>
          <tr><td>Sun</td><td>Mon</td><td>Tue</td><td>Wed</td><td>Thu</td><td>Fri</td><td>Sat</td></tr>
          <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr>
          <tr><td>8</td><td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td><td>13</td><td>14</td></tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks - that's nice and clear. (the background colour was just for demonstration)

I can now see that my original :not() wasn't precise enough, and thus was still appling to all tables, not just the outer-table.