# How to send variable from blade to controller without changing the url

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6, laravel-controller, laravel-route

In blade I have a list of books. I want to choose a specific book to show its information. And to do so I want to send with href the id of the book to my controller passing through route.

For example i have

```
 <div class="body text-center">
 <a href="{{HERE!}}"><h6><b>{{($book->getName())}}</b></h6></a>
 </div>
```

In href I want to add $bookId = $book->id and the route name so I can call the route with the specific name which calls a method in a controller which can use the variable $bookId

```
 Route::get('/infromation','Books\BookController@index')->name('info');
```

Comment: I'm not sure to get what you want. You don't want to change the URL but you want to add the ID. (Perhaps a POST request?). Does the route should return the `index` as well?

Comment: url: /books -> where all books are shown
I select one of the books and I want the shown url to become: /{book-name}/info or just /info and also i want to send the selected book's id to the controller Bookcontroller.

Comment: If you want the book name in the URL is recommended you to have a [slug](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: I don't know. I will take a look

Comment: Also, I don't recommend URL like `/info` without using `id` or `slug` because, in my opinion, it provide a bad user experience when trying to access the resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's two propositions:

- The first one is to use [spatie/laravel-sluggable](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-sluggable) to have the book name in the URL
- The second one is to access the book without changing the URL with a POST request

> Using `spatie/laravel-sluggable`

*The slug will be generated automatically from `name` when the book is created.*

**your-migration.php**

```php
 Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('slug')->unique()->index();
    $table->string('name');
    // ...
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**web.php**

```php
// Change the URIs as you want. `{book}` is mandatory to retrieve the book though.
Route::get('/books','Books\BookController@index')->name('book.index');
Route::get('/books/{book}','Books\BookController@show')->name('book.show');
```

**Book.php**

```php
use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Spatie\Sluggable\SlugOptions;

class Book extends Model
{
    use HasSlug;

    protected $guarded = [];

    public function getSlugOptions()
    {
        // Adapt with what you want
        return SlugOptions::create()
            ->generateSlugsFrom('name')
            ->saveSlugsTo('slug')
            ->doNotGenerateSlugsOnUpdate();
    }

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }

}
```

**BookController.php**

```php
class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('book.index');
    }

    public function show(Book $book)
    {
        // $book is retrieving using Model Binding: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding 
        return view('book.show', compact('book'));
    }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```php
<div class="body text-center">
    <a href="{{ route('book.show', $book) }}">
        <h6><b>{{ $book->getName() }}</b></h6>
    </a>
</div>
```

---

> Using POST request (URI does not change) and without SLUG

*I wouldn't recommend using this for the user experience.*

- *The user cannot bookmark the book or share the link with someone else*
- *When refreshing the page, it will prompt to the user if he want to re-submit the form request*

**web.php**

```php
Route::get('/books','Books\BookController@index')->name('book.index');
Route::post('/books','Books\BookController@show')->name('book.show');
```

**BookController.php**

```php
class BookController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('book.index');
    }

    public function show()
    {
        $book = Book::findOrFail(request('book_id'));
        return view('book.show', compact('book'));
    }
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```php
<div class="body text-center">
    <form action="{{ route('book.show') }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        <input type="hidden" value="{{ $book->id }}" name="book_id">
        <h6>
            <button type="submit"> 
                <b>{{ $book->getName() }}</b>
            </button>
        </h6>
    </form>
</div>
```

*You can remove the default button style to make it looks like a link
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45890842/8068675*

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this**

```
    <form action="/BookName/information/<?php echo $book->id; ?>" method="post">
      <div class="body text-center">
       <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="{{ $book->id }}">
       <a href="/information/<?php echo $book->id; ?>">
          <button type="submit" name="book_information" class="btn btn-primary"> 
            <h6>
              <b>{{($book->getName())}}</b> 
            </h6>
         </button>
     </div>

   </form> 

    // make route like this
    Route::post('/BookName/information/{id}','Books\BookController@index');

    // Access the that id in controller
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        echo $request->book_id;
    }
```

Comment: Okay but I don't want to show the id on the url is it possible to send the id and keeping the url '/information' or sending the id and changing the url to '/bookName/information'?

Comment: I update my answer as per what you say, so please check